# How do I write this as a regular expression?

Tags: regex, command-line

I have a sequence of code that I need to be able to find in several different files quickly.  It has the form:

```
<?php
//{{56541616
```

where the 8-digit number can be any sequence of numbers and letters.  I'd like to use regular expressions to locate the code, but I'm still new to them, and this is complex enough that it's throwing me.  Here's what I came up with for the regex, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
"<\?/php/n//\{\{[:alnum:]{8}"
```

any advice on what I'm doing wrong/what the actual regular expression should be?

UPDATE: I haven't been able to get any of the answers to do what I want.  To add more explanation to what I'm trying to do, there's a piece of code that I need to remove from several files, and the sequence above is the start of that code that needs removing.  Then end is similar:

```
//}}18420732
?>
```

again, the 8-digit code can be any number + letter sequence.  I'm trying to use awk with

```
 /<string1>/,/<string2>/
```

to find the range of lines in between.  So, for instance using one of the answers given + my interpretation of that for the second line, I'm putting this into command line:

```
awk {/<\?php\n\/\/\{\{([:alnum:]{8})/,/\/\/\}\}([:alnum:]{8})\n\?/} index.php
```

and I get this response:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Here's another example of something I tried + result.

```
awk /<\?php\n\/\/\{\{[:alnum:]{8}/,/\/\/\}\}[:alnum:]{8}\n\?>/ index.php
-bash: ?phpn//{{[:alnum:]{8}/,///}}[:alnum:]{8}n?/: No such file or directory
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Try it:
`/<\?php\s*\/{2}\{\{(\w{8})/i`

Comment: what does the \s* part do?  Is it another way to say "new line"?

Answer (score 1):

**Your regex**:

> "<\?/php/n//\{\{[:alnum:]{8}"

**What's wrong**:

- Quoting - a regex in most languages has to start and end with a / character, not quotes.
- The unnecessary use of / before php
- Using / instead of \ before the n (for matching newline)
- Not escaping the / characters that's in your text, since that is a special character

**The solution**:

- /<\?php\n\/\/\{\{([:alnum:]{8})/
- The / characters have been escaped, the slash before n corrected, and paranthesis surround the "[:alnum:]{8}" part. The paranthesis are so that the 8-digit code will be captured in the variable $1 which you can then use in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

`<\?php\s\/\/\{\{[0-9]{8}`